Lua. Why does the for loop close on the first occurrence of if on the second line?
I am trying to detect all the Towns in the Street object, inside, that have child wind_.
But the loop terminates after processing a single Town object, why?
for _, object in ipairs(game.Workspace.Street: GetChildren()) do
    if object.Name == "Town" then
        for _, object in ipairs(object.house:children()) do
            if string.sub(object.Name, 1, 5) == "wind_" then
                object.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Light blue")
            end
        end
    end
end

As expected, the for loop goes through all Town objects.

Maybe object.Name is nil, so string.sub raises an error and exits the loop?

You say the loop terminates after processing a single Town object and a few lines later you say that the for loop goes through all Town objects. The only way for this to work is to have a single Town object. Please clarify.
printing the values will help you find out why your conditions are not met.

maybe :children() on line 3 should be :GetChildren() or did you make a custom function? also you're assigning the variable object twice in both loops, so one will overwrite the other.
